# How to transfer pictures from Samsung S360 to PC?

Tags: photos

We would like to transfer pictures from the camera to a PC.

How can we do this?

Do we need to buy a cable or software?

Comment: Did it not come with a USB cable

Comment: No. Did not come with USB cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any description about the camera, but check for two things:

- Does the camera have or support memory cards in any form
- Are there any plugs for USB/Mini-USB, if yes, try plugging it into your computer with a cable. I'm not sure, but Linux should recognize the camera as a removeable device immediately...Windows, I have no idea.